# Resolving problem in proof of Theorem 1 in V. Sós "On the distribution mod 1 of the sequence $n\alpha$"

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I am reading V. Sós' "On the distribution mod 1 of the sequence $n\alpha$" which can be found on page 127 of [its journal issue](http://annales-math.elte.hu/archive.html).  This is one of the early proofs of the "three gap theorem" that there are at most three gaps between consecutive points in the points $n \alpha \mod 1$ for $0 \leq n \leq N$.  In her proof of Theorem 1 at the bottom of p. 130 she is dealing with Case B where $N - k_1 < k_{\ell} < k_N$ and $k_{\ell+1} = k_{\ell} + k_1 - k_n$.  She says that $n + k_N - k_{\ell} > N$, which, using $k_N \geq k_{\ell}$ gives $n >N$. I can verify both premises but this chain of logic does not work. I suspect that there is a correct argument for concluding that $n > N$ as Sós' proof is well accepted in the literature but I have not found it yet.  I thought perhaps we need to use $N-k_1 < k_{\ell}$ which is the only restriction in Case B that has not been used yet, but so far I have not figured out a way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have patched Sos' argument by reading [Świerczkowski, S.
"On successive settings of an arc on the circumference of a circle."
Fund. Math. 46 (1959), pp187–189](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-46-2-187-189).  Replacing the "Case B" argument on p.130 of Sos' article with the following completes the proof

Note that if
$$k_{N-1}\alpha-, i\alpha-, 0-$$
then either $i= k_N$ or $i > N$. Thus Lemma 1 implies that $k_{N-1}=k_{N}-k_1$.  If $n \geq k_{l} + k_1 - k_N$ then remark 8 gives
$$
(k_N-k_1)\alpha-, (n-k_l+k_N-k_1)\alpha-, 0
$$
which the same as
$$
k_{N-1}\alpha-,  (n-k_l+k_N-k_1)\alpha-, 0-
$$
So either

- $n-k_l+k_N-k_1 = k_N$ which implies $n > N$ because in Case B, $N-k_1 < k_l$; or
- $n-k_l+k_N-k_1 > N$ which implies $n > N$ because $n \geq k_{l} + k_1 - k_N$.

If $n < k_{l} + k_1 - k_N$ we use remark 8 to obtain
$$
(k_l-n)\alpha-, 0-, (k_l-k_1-k_N-n)\alpha-
$$
And since the entire interval has the width of
$$
k_{N-1}\alpha-, 0-,
$$ we get
$$
k_{N-1}\alpha-, (k_l-n)\alpha-, 0-, (k_l-k_1-k_N-n)\alpha-
$$
so either

- $k_l-n = k_N$ which implies $k_N < k_l$ for a contradiction with the Case B condition $k_l < k_N$; or
- $k_l-n > N$ which implies that $k_l > N$ for another contradiction.